# How can I keep this DIV background from moving w/ the browser window?

Tags: css, html, joomla, background

I have a website I am working on: http://digitaldemo.net/sadj/

If you look at it, the overall page background is the image with the cars. Then the header is
made up of that highway signs image and the corner banner overlays it.

The dilemma is that if you resize the browser window, the signs slide behind the corner banner.
I need them to stay in place.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could combine the signs image with the background.

Comment: The image signs are a background image in and of themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template.css file (line 156) add the following code to `.nav-signs { }`

```
min-width: 1340px;
```

You can of course change the pixel value to whatever you feel is best.

Basically, this defines the minimum width for something, therefore cannot be made smaller. When you make your browser size smaller, it takes the `min-width` into account and won't move it anymore once it reaches 1340px.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried, but it's still doing it. The signs slide behind the corner banner when I size the browser down.

Comment: 1420px put the signs too far away from the corner banner. But 1340px did the trick. How come that works? I'm glad it does, don't get me wrong. I'd just like to understand why.